# R geom_tile ggplot2 what kind of stat is applied?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, heatmap

I used `geom_tile()` for plot 3 variables on the same graph... with

```
tile_ruined_coop<-ggplot(data=df.1[sel1,])+
  geom_tile(aes(x=bonus, y=malus, fill=rf/300))+
  scale_fill_gradient(name="vr")+
  facet_grid(Seuil_out_coop_i ~ nb_coop_init)
tile_ruined_coop
```

and I am pleased with the result !

[image: ggplot2 geom_tile exemple]

But What kind of statistical treatment is applied to `fill` ? Is this a mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To plot the mean of the fill values you should aggregate your values, before plotting. The scale_colour_gradient(...) does not work on the data level, but on the visualization level.
Let's start with a toy Dataframe to build a reproducible example to work with.

```
mydata = expand.grid(bonus = seq(0, 1, 0.25), malus = seq(0, 1, 0.25), type = c("Risquophile","Moyen","Risquophobe"))
mydata = do.call("rbind",replicate(40, mydata, simplify = FALSE))
mydata$value= runif(nrow(mydata), min=0, max=50)
mydata$coop = "cooperative"
```

Now, before plotting I suggest you to calculate the mean over your groups of 40 values, and for this operation  like to use the *dplyr* package:

```
library(dplyr)
data = mydata %>% group_by("bonus","malus","type","coop") %>% summarise(vr=mean(value))
```

Tow you have your dataset ready to plot with *ggplot2*:

```
library(ggplot2)
g = ggplot(data, aes(x=bonus,y=malus,fill=vr))
g = g + geom_tile()
g = g + facet_grid(type~coop)
```

and this is the result:
[image: tile plot]

where you are sure that the fill value is exactly the mean of your values.
Is this what you expected?

Comment: Yes thank you Fabio! It could be great for ggplot to be able to play whit basic stat with fill ! :-)

Comment: I think that the two things are intentended to be de-coupled. ggplot acts like a grammar for visualization, aggregate or dplyr is for 'data shaping'

Answer (score 3):

It uses `stat_identity` as can be seen in the documentation. You can test that easily:

```
DF <- data.frame(x=c(rep(1:2, 2), 1), 
                 y=c(rep(1:2, each=2), 1), 
                 fill=1:5)

#  x y fill
#1 1 1    1
#2 2 1    2
#3 1 2    3
#4 2 2    4
#5 1 1    5

p <- ggplot(data=DF) +
  geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=fill))

print(p)
```

[image]

As you see the fill value for the 1/1 combination is 5. If you use factors it's even more clear what happens:

```
p <- ggplot(data=DF) +
  geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=factor(fill)))

print(p)
```

[image]

If you want to depict means, I'd suggest to calculate them outside of ggplot2:

```
library(plyr)
DF1 <- ddply(DF, .(x, y), summarize, fill=mean(fill))
p <- ggplot(data=DF1) +
  geom_tile(aes(x=x, y=y, fill=fill))

print(p)
```

[image]

That's easier than trying to find out if `stat_summary` can play with `geom_tile` somehow (I doubt it).

Comment: thank you ! so if I want to use ddply for find mean of fill value grouping by bonus and malus ... but I would like to conserve all other variable?, how can Y do

Comment: ok with `aggregate()` I have find a solution ! It could be cool to have this kind stat solution with ggplot2

Answer (score -1):

scale_fill() and geom_tile() apply no statistics -or better apply stat_identity()- to your fill value=rf/300. It just computes how many colors you use and then generates the colors with the munsell function 'mnsl()'. If you want to apply some statistics only to the colors displayed you should use:

```
scale_colour_gradient(trans = "log")
```

or

```
scale_colour_gradient(trans = "sqrt")
```

Changing the colors among the tiles could not be the best idea since the plots have to be comparable, and you compare the values by their colours. Hope this helps

Comment: Tank's Fabio, but if I would like to plot the mean of fill value how can Y do? trans = "mean" doesn't exist :-S

Comment: You want the overall mean among the 'risquophile', 'moyen' and 'risquophobe'?

Comment: I have 40 simulation for each variable pool so I would like to calcul the mean result for each variable configuration. For exemple bonus = 0, malus = 0 risquophile ... and bonus = 0 malus = 2 risquophile... and so on