# Summarising data before plotting with geom_tile() renders different results

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have noticed that when plotting with `ggplot2`'s `geom_tile()`, summarising the data before plotting renders a completely different result than when it is not pre-summarised. I don't understand why.

For a dataframe with three columns, `year` (character), `state` (character) and `profit` (numeric), consider the following examples:

```
# Plot straight away 

data %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=year, y=state)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=profit)) 

# Summarise before plotting

data %>% group_by(year, state) %>% summarize(profit_mean = mean(profit)) %>%
ungroup() %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=year, y=state)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=profit_mean))
```

These two examples render two different tile plots - the values are quite different. I thought that these two methods of plotting would be analogous and that `ggplot2` would take a mean automatically - is that not so?

I tried reproducing this error on a smaller subset of data, but it didn't appear. What could be going on here?

Comment: Because in the second it is `mean` value and in the first, it is using the original values of the column with `stat_identity`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341581/r-geom-tile-ggplot2-what-kind-of-stat-is-applied

Comment: Thank you, can I ask, how is it using the original values? Is it taking a sum or what does this mean?

Comment: It uses the original data.  You can check the link i showed.  Also, in the documentaiton of `?stat_identity` -`The identity statistic leaves the data unchanged.`

Comment: By default, the args for `geom_tile` are `args(geom_tile)#
function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", 
    ..., linejoin = "mitre", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
    inherit.aes = TRUE)` it is the 'identity' for stat

Comment: The default (probably) is overplotting the data, so one row ends up on top, and that's the value that you see. Just like if you plot 10 points with different colors but the same x,y coordinates - one point ends up on top.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas, I couldn't understand what it means to leave data unchanged, but I think now I do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP, this was a very interesting question.

First, let's get this out of the way.  It is clear what plotting the summary of your data is plotting just that: the summary.  You are summarizing via mean, so what is plotted equals the mean of the values for each tile.

The *actual* question here is: If you have a dataset containing more than one value per tile, what is the result of plotting the "non-summarized" dataset?

User @akrun is correct: the default `stat` used for `geom_tile` is `stat="identity"`, but it might not be clear what that exactly means.  It says it "leaves the data unchanged"... but that's not clear what that means here.

#### Illustrative Example Dataset

For purposes of demonstration, I'll create an illustrative dataset, which will answer the question very clearly.  I'm creating two individual datasets `df1` and `df2`, which each contain 4 "tiles" of data.  The difference between these is that the values themselves for the tiles are different.  I've include text labels on each tile for more clarity.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

df1 <- data.frame(
  x=rep(paste("Test",1:2), 2),
  y=rep(c("A", "B"), each=2),
  value=c(5,15,20,25)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  x=rep(paste("Test",1:2), 2),
  y=rep(c("A", "B"), each=2),
  value=c(10,5,25,15)
)

tile1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x,y, fill=value, label=value)) +
  geom_tile() + geom_text() + labs(title="df1")

tile2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x,y, fill=value, label=value)) +
  geom_tile() + geom_text() + labs(title="df2")

plot_grid(tile1, tile2)
```

[image]

#### Plotting the Combined Data Frame

Each of the data frames `df1` and `df2` contain only one value per tile, so in order to see how that changes when we have more than one value per tile, we need to combine them into one so that each tile will contain 2 values.  In this example, we are going to combine them in two ways:  first `df1` then `df2`, and the other way is `df2` first, then `df1`.

```
df12 <- rbind(df1, df2)
df21 <- rbind(df2, df1)
```

Now, if we plot each of those as before and compare, the reason for the discrepancy the OP posted should be quite obvious.  I'm including the value for each tile for each originating dataset to make things super-clear.

```
tile12 <- ggplot(df12, aes(x,y, fill=value, label=value)) +
  geom_tile() + labs(title="df1, then df2") +
  geom_text(data=df1, aes(label=paste("df1:",value)), nudge_y=0.1) +
  geom_text(data=df2, aes(label=paste("df2:",value)), nudge_y=-0.1)

tile21 <- ggplot(df21, aes(x,y, fill=value, label=value)) +
  geom_tile() + labs(title="df2, then df1") +
  geom_text(data=df1, aes(label=paste("df1:",value)), nudge_y=0.1) +
  geom_text(data=df2, aes(label=paste("df2:",value)), nudge_y=-0.1)

plot_grid(tile12, tile21)
```

[image]

Note that the legend colorbar value does not change, so it's not doing an addition.  Plus, since we know it's `stat="identity"`, we know this should not be the case.  When we use the dataset that contains first observations from `df1`, then observations from `df2`, the value plotted is the one from `df2`.  When we use the dataset that contains observations first from `df2`, then from `df1`, the value plotted is the one from `df1`.

Given this piece of information, it can be clear that the value shown in `geom_tile()` when using `stat="identity"` (default argument) **corresponds to the last observation for that particular tile represented in the data frame**.

So, that's the reason why your plot looks odd OP.  You can either summarize beforehand as you have done, or use `stat_summary(geom="tile"...` to do the transformation in one go within `ggplot`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This has really allowed me to understand what is going on there.

Comment: It was not obvious to me this was the way it worked (I would wager it would be obvious to no one), but your question piqued my curiosity.  I'm glad I got the chance to examine this and I hope it will help others.